# The other solution of the Hermite equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Hermite equation is

$$ y'' - 2x y' + 2 \nu  y = 0  .  $$

By using the Laplace method, people get a solution

$$ y = A \int_C \frac{ e^{xt - t^2/4} }{t^{\nu+1}}dt ,  $$

where $C$, the path of integration,  must be chosen so that

$$ \frac{ e^{xt - t^2/4} }{t^{\nu }} \bigg|_{\partial C } = 0 . $$

Now suppose $\nu$ is a non-negative integer. People get a solution by choosing the contour $C$ as a circle around the origin.

My question is, how about the other solution? Which path should we take?

Moreover, what if $\nu$ is a negative integer? In this case, taking $C$ as a circle around the origin will just yield a vanishing function.

Comment: See here http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/series/series06/series06.html

Comment: What makes you think a different choice of contour will yield something different? Also, the Hermite Equations have a solution in the Error Functions, which is possibly preferable for the standard estimates you get